# Compliance Tag Field not available with Microsoft Graph API filter

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Using the Microsoft Graph API (v1.0) sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items end-point to try and find any new documents that have had a Compliance Tag applied.  In the fields I see _ComplianceTagWrittenTime but when I supply that field into the filter I'm given 'field not recognized' error

Here is the list of fields

```
"fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"etag\"",
                "FileLeafRef": "Test.docx",
                "id": "1",
                "ContentType": "Document",
                "Created": "2019-06-27T18:08:27Z",
                "AuthorLookupId": "6",
                "Modified": "2020-01-05T23:39:12Z",
                "EditorLookupId": "6",
                "_CheckinComment": "",
                "LinkFilenameNoMenu": "Test.docx",
                "LinkFilename": "Test.docx",
                "DocIcon": "docx",
                "FileSizeDisplay": "19243",
                "ItemChildCount": "0",
                "FolderChildCount": "0",
                "_ComplianceFlags": "7",
                "_ComplianceTag": "Short Record",
                "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "2020-11-02T19:41:16Z",
                "_ComplianceTagUserId": "6",
                "_IsRecord": "7",
                "_CommentCount": "",
                "_LikeCount": "",
                "_DisplayName": "",
                "Edit": "0",
                "_UIVersionString": "6.0",
                "ParentVersionStringLookupId": "1",
                "ParentLeafNameLookupId": "1"
            }
```

This call works [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields&filter=fields/Modified](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items?expand=fields&filter=fields/Modified) gt '2019-01-05T23:39:12Z'

but this one [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields&filter=fields/_ComplianceTagWrittenTime](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items?expand=fields&filter=fields/_ComplianceTagWrittenTime) gt '2019-01-05T23:39:12Z'
returns

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "A provided field name is not recognized",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-03T17:33:52",
            "request-id": "{request-id}",
            "client-request-id": "{client-id}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot filter the list items as of now as there is no support for it. Please upvote an already existing feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38989819-sharepoint-listitem-filter-support-on-fields)

Comment: Moving this to Answer

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot filter the list items as of now as there is no support for it. Please upvote an already existing feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38989819-sharepoint-listitem-filter-support-on-fields).